# Pipe Date (Angular)

Tags: angular, pipe

Tengo un servidor que me manda las fechas de al siguiente manera
"date : 20200930"
pero me gustaría obtener el siguiente resultado
"Semtember 16, 2020"

Comment: y qué intentaste?

Comment: @Pollo los pipes que me angular para los date pero me lo pones como "Enero 01, 1970"

Comment: ¿Y por qué no mandas la fecha formateada desde la consulta de la bd?

Answer (score 0):

No se necesita crear un pipe personalizado para mostrar la información, sin embargo si lo necesitas por medio de un pipe te toca hacer uno personalizado. te envió estas soluciones

- Pipe personalizado

https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/angularya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=20&codigo=20&inicio=0

Dentro de este pipe, tienes que identificar como viene siempre la fecha

2020 Primeros 4 dígitos años

09 luego 2 dígitos de mes

30 luego 2 días de día

ahora si viene en numero lo transformas a string para manejarlo mas fácil y lo partes en 3 (dia mes año), lo puedes partir con substring
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice

Luego solo retornas en este pipe un objeto de tipo Date con new Date(año,mes,dia)
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

- sin pipe

en el servicio que te llega la data solo realiza el ultimo paso de dividir en 3 (año mes dia) el string y guardas este resultado en una variable para mostrar en el html y si lo quieres global solo crea un servicio

- Cambia el codigo en el servidor

Pide que te cambien como se retorna la data para que sea mas fácil para ti manejarlo en front